# Near horizon terrain rendering

Tags: memory, rendering, openscenegraph

Just a query on terrain rendering concept.

I have been trying to render a terrain at near horizon level at low level. This has always result in crashes.

I believe that it is because that at horizon I would need to pull in more nodes from my database as the region I am rendering is much larger as compared to rendering straight looking top down. This would have the effect of overloading my memory. Am I correct?

Also specific to the rendering library I am using - OpenSCeneGraph, I understand that when I am rendering at a particular resolution level, even lower resolution nodes and tiles are also loaded into the memory. Am I also correct?

Is there any way to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, looking towards the horizon may pull in more nodes because the view frustum covers them. But far off nodes should be lower detail. I'm assuming this terrain database was built with VPB? You can turn down the LOD scale (I think there might even be a keyboard abbreviation for this) to reduce overall scene detail.

OSG's PagedLOD node retains all lower LOD levels in order to be able to rapidly downshift the LOD if necessary.

Monitor you memory consumption when it crashes to see if it's running out of resources. Also, set OSG's Notify level up to DEBUG and watch the output to see if you see any explanation of what is failing.